# To what kind of inertial observer would these vectors correspond to?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, inertial-frames

In special relativity, consider the following frame field:

$e_0=\partial_t$,   $e_1=\cos z\, \partial_x−\sin z\, \partial_y$,  $e_2=\sin z\, \partial_x+\cos z\, \partial_y$,  $e_3=\partial_z$.

This obeys $g(e_i,e_j)=\eta_{ij}$, $\nabla_{e_0}e_i=0$, for $i=0,1,2,3$, and represents therefore an inertial, non-rotating frame.

However, this can't be obtained via a Lorentz tranformation from a "regular" Lorentz frame with basis vectors $\partial_t, \partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$.

My question is: physically, what kind of observer is this frame describing?

Comment: This is not a rotation. If you exchange z for $\theta$ then its a rotation, but z is not a constant parameter, its a coordinate.

Comment: My bad, but note that  'observer' is a local construct. And each observer in this frame differs from observer at origin by a rotation (different for different observers) and spatial translation

Comment: Maybe this [photo of a skyscraper](http://images.skyscrapercenter.com/building/RevolutionTower_Ext-Up_(cc)Rubydiazmendez.jpg) will be useful, at different floors we have inertial observers at rest with each other, but their orientation differs from floor to floor.

Comment: Yes that photo helped a lot, i think i got it,thanks :)